# Only 32 bit available in Oracle VM - Hadoop Installation

Tags: hadoop, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am a newbie to Hadoop. To get some hands on, I am trying to set up Hadoop in my laptop.

I installed oracle vm from the following link:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/downloads/index.html

I used the file - Windows Installer (see the attached).

When I try to create a new VM, It displays only 32 bit OS. I am not sure why isn't displaying a 64 bit OS. Can someone help me on this??

Regards,

[image: Oracle VM]

[image: Linux Versions in VM]

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that processor is having virtualization support.And it should be enabled in Bios. [link](http://www.intel.com/support/processors/sb/cs-030729.htm).